# Suspending a group of users and reactivating them using devise cancan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, cancan

I have a bunch of users who are identified by belongs_to practice

All users who are not admins (has_role? :admin) are members of a practice.

I want to be able to suspend practice users so that they are all read only.

I then want to be able to reactivate them.

Am using devise and cancan / rolify

Am confused about the best way to accomplish this.

So user might have role :practice_super_user or :practice_assistant

When I suspend them, I want to allow them to still access their information but only read only (no add or update).

Then wehn I reactivate them, I'd like them to return to their original abilities.

Is there an easy way to do this? What's the most logical way?

I'm concerned that I'll lose the original role if I just change the role to :read_only
Or
I'll have to go through and edit every controller...etc if I try and hang it off a parameter from practice e.g Practice.suspended == true

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up adding a role of suspended

Applying it to all users of the practice by adding this to my update controller

```
if @practice.suspended == true
      @practice.users.each do |user|
        user.add_role(:suspended)
      end
    else
      @users = @practice.users
      @users.each do |user|
        user.remove_role(:suspended)
      end
    end
```

then putting

```
if user.has_role? :suspended
  can :read, Practice, :id => user.practice_id
  can :read, Task, :practice_id => user.practice_id
  can :read, Client, :practice_id => user.practice_id
else
  all my other abilities
```

Only works where users can have multiple roles, and I don't imagine it is the most elegant way to do it, but it worked and might help somebody else struggling with this.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you add a boolean field to your User model called `suspended`.

Then check in CanCan  whether it is set.

**ability.rb**

```
unless user.suspended?
  # Define abilities here.
end
```

This will make sure a user only has access to these abilities when he is not suspended.

To unsuspend him, you only have to set `suspended = false`.

This way you don't have to change any of your existing roles and users will have access to everything again as soon as they are no longer suspended.

Comment: Hi, this is almost there I think.
Just having a problem with user.practice.suspended? in the ability model whcih is giving me an undefined method error

Comment: Shouldn't it be `user.suspended?`. The user is suspended right? Not the practice.

Comment: No, all the users of the practice are either suspended or not suspended. In theory I could apply suspended to all the users and then remove from all the users but that seems to be slightly more complex when it's really the practice that is switched on or off, e.g. for non-payment.

Comment: Okay in that case, can you show me the complete error message?

Comment: I asked the question in slightly more generic way, as I still don't understand why I can't get those attributes.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19572131/access-attributes-from-associated-model-in-model