# Access attributes from associated model in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I'm trying to apply a rule to an ability class

Each user in my application (except admins, but we'll ignore that) belongs_to a practice, defined in another model.

The practice may want to be suspended from access for one reason or another.

I want to say in my ability model

```
if user.practice.suspended? 
 can :read, Client, :practice_id => user.practice_id
else 
can :manage, CLient, :practice_id => user.practice_id
etc....
```

But for some reason, whilst I can use

```
user.practice_id
```

in the ability model
I can't use

```
user.practice.<attribute>
```

Any ideas for a way around that?

models/user.rb

```
belongs_to :practice
```

models/practice.rb

A practice has many users. 
The only user who won't have a practice are those with role :admin

```
has_many :users
```

Comment: What do you mean by *I can't use*? Do you get an error? Which one exactly?

Comment: could you post some code from your models?

Comment: paste in how you build relations between user and practice, if you can't call user.practice.attribute something tells me you have set up relations in a wrong way.

Comment: Can you try this? `can :manage, Client, :practice => { :practice_id => user.practice.id }`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the relationships backwards.

It should be that "User has_many (or has_one) practice" and "Practice belongs_to user". This would signify that the foreign_key (in this case user_id) is actually in the practice table instead of the user table.

Try this:

User.rb

```
has_one :practice
```

Practice.rb

```
belongs_to :user
```

Create a migration to add user_id to practice

```
add_column :practices, :user_id, :integer
```

Then you can call practice from user like so:

```
user.practice.x
```

Comment: Each practice (a company) will have many users.
So each user has practice_id, signifying which practice they belong to.  Have I got that the right way around?

Comment: okay, I suppose that makes sense... can users belong to multiple practices though?

Comment: No. Imagine the practive a company, where all users from that practice are workingon that company's clients. So any user is an employee of that practice and would thus only have 1 practice.